# How can I terminate my threads with blocking functions/procedures?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I use `TThread` in my application and I have a LOT of functions that I would like to use inside of it. 
Functions that I use, take time to complete, so it's not ideal to use them in threads. That's why I was wondering if there's a way other than just copy & paste the function/procedure and then put (maybe inject) my `terminated` flags into the function.
I don't want to use `TerminateThread` API!

A short example:

```
procedure MyProcedure;
begin
 // some work that takes time over a few lines of code
 // add/inject terminated flag?!
 // try... finally...
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
 MyProcedure;
 // or copy and paste myprocedure
end;
```

So is there an efficient way to write procedures/functions that help me with the `terminated` flag? Also the procedures/functions should be global so other functions/procedures can call them too.

Comment: There's no way you can regularly check for the 'terminated' flag in myprocedure?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I can't. The `terminated` flag is a member of the `TThread` class.

Comment: So myprocedure has no idea in what thread it's running in. In that case, in what way you can even call TerminateThread?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I don't use `TerminatedThread`. I use the `TThread`'s `Terminate` procedure.

Comment: In your question, you mentioned you don't want to call TerminateThread. I inquired, how could you possibly call it. I'm probably misunderstanding your question..

Comment: You could introduce a callback method into the procedure call. If assigned (a call from a thread), make the callback, otherwise (from a normal procedure) skip the call. The callback method can check for the terminated flag.

Comment: @LU RD - I guess passing a reference to the thread would serve the same. What if the callback/reference is overwritten by another thread? What should be blocking where? I can't really imagine how the real case looks like..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, passing the thread reference would hide the logic behind the purpose of the callback. The callback reference lives on the stack, nothing can overwrite that inside MyProcedure.

Comment: @LU RD - Conceptually a callback might be better than passing a reference, it would've serve for the purpose nevertheless. I couldn't, however, for the life of me, think of that the basis of this question is failing to notice that you could pass *something* to the procedure.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, hesitating to break the DRY principle is one step in the right direction. How to implement it may need some guidance, especially without nesting dependencies.

Comment: @LURD - Ok, I think I see your point. Thank you for helping me clearing my confusion. :) I can clear my noise here if anyone wants it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option is to introduce a callback method into your procedure call.
If the callback method is Assigned (when called from a thread) make the call and take action.

When calling `MyProcedure` from elsewhere, pass nil to the procedure.

```
Type
  TAbortProc = function : boolean of object;

procedure MyProcedure( AbortProc : TAbortProc);
begin
  //...
  if (Assigned(AbortProc) and AbortProc) then
    Exit;
  //...
end;


function MyThread.AbortOperation : Boolean;
begin
  Result := Terminated;
end;
```

The reason why I avoid passing the thread reference instead of a callback method, is to hide the thread logic (and dependency) from `MyProcedure`.

Comment: That's actually a good idea and it works! Thank you for this!